# Python-Linux: run script in background from script

Tags: python, centos, daemon, spawn

I've been trying os.spawnv to run script in background

```
os.spawnv(os.P_NOWAIT, "/home/R/daemon_excel.py", ["arg1", "arg3", "arg2"])
```

but daemon_excel.py doesn´t run

Comment: Do you wait after spawning the process, as it will probably be killed when the parent exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative: use `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.check_call("/home/R/daemon_excel.py arg1 arg3 arg2 &", shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this work!
what is the diferent between "subprocess.check_call" and "subprocess.call"?

Comment: `check_call()` raises an exception of the subprocess had an error